# Why aren't my scripts running when called from cron and other scheduled services?

Tags: python, bash, cron

I'm simply trying to trigger a script to run every so often to download items into a directory.

I have a python script that downloads a directory. I've tried running the python script directly from cron....

```
5 * * * * python /home/yt/pybox/boxclient.py -U email@address.com -td -Pd moremusic/youtube
```

Even having cron call a bash script that runs the python script....

```
5 * * * * cd /home/yt/yxbox/runscript
```

I've even setup a inotifywait that listens to cron doing a touch command and then triggering the python script from there....

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

inotifywait -mr -e ATTRIB * |

while read dir ev file;
do
   python boxclient.py -U email@address.com -td -Pd moremusic/youtube;
done;
```

And all those ways give me this error which I'm lost on:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "boxclient.py", line 224, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "boxclient.py", line 190, in main
    (parser, options, args) = parse_args(argv)
  File "boxclient.py", line 80, in parse_args
    return (parser, options, decode_args(args, options))
  File "/home/yt/pybox/pybox/utils.py", line 134, in decode_args
    setattr(options, attr, value.decode(ENCODING))
TypeError: decode() argument 1 must be string, not None
```

everything runs fine when I run the python and the bash script on the cl.

Comment: Change `python` for `/bin/python` or whatever coming from `which python`.

Comment: Or better, use `/usr/bin/env python` for portability.

Comment: Cron runs with very little of the environment set up which leads scripts that assume a login shell to fail; where does ECODING come from in your example?

Comment: ENCODING = sys.stdin.encoding # typically "UTF-8" ... its part of utils.py

Comment: but even when the script attempts to run from an inotifywait script it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to lose the space between `-U` and `email@address.com`.  The syntax is:

```
python pybox/boxclient.py -Ubob -td -Pd dir1/dir2
```

(from https://github.com/hzheng/pybox).  So in Cron try:

```
5 * * * * /usr/bin/env python /home/yt/pybox/boxclient.py -Uemail@address.com -td -Pd moremusic/youtube
```

In general, short-form options do not take a space between the argument and its parameter, while long-form options do.  So it's either `-Uemail@address.com` or `--username email@address.com`.

Comment: thats only a typo from posting on here, like i mentioned the actual script runs fine when ran manually. I gotten the script to work numerous times. just not as a scheduled cron